# BigQuery CONTAINS or REGEX_MATCH for exact match within fields

Tags: google-bigquery

This may be an amateur question, however how do I find a matching string within a field by using another field matching by specific field value.

For instance:

Field_A = 'The Dog Ate The Salisbury Steak'

Field_B = 'Sal'

Running WHERE Field_A CONTAINS Field_B  will return true, even though Sal is not isolated within Field_A.

How do I query using CONTAINS but specify an exact match such as:

Field_A = 'The Dog Ate The Salisbury Steak'
Field_B = 'Sal'
Will return False

But..

Field_A = 'The Dog Ate The Sal'

Field_B = 'Sal'

Will return true

I tried REGEX but it seems that I cannot specify a field and it must be instead an actual string, so I can't use REGEX_MATCH(Field_A, '^'Field_B'$')

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you mean by 'isolated' but if you need to find a word within sentence, then splitting on space might work. I.e. you use SPLIT to separate field_a into multiple words, and if any of them is exactly the same as field_b, you have a match:

```
select some(split(a, ' ') = b) from
(select 'The Dog Ate The Salisbury Steak' a, 'Sal' b),
(select 'The Dog Ate The Sal' a, 'Sal' b)
```

returns

```
1   false    
2   true
```

Comment: I've used this with two additions. First, in my case all substrings separated by non-letters were potential matches, so I changed non-letters to spaces with `regexp_replace` before splitting. Second, while `some(...)` and `every(...)` can unfortunately not be used in the `where` clause, they can be used in the `omit record if` clause. So what I ended up with is `omit record if every(split(regexp_replace(a,r'[^a-z]',' '),' ') != b)`.